# How to fix Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target?

Tags: ios, ios7, applepay

I tried to implement **Apple Pay** in my app, but I am getting a error such that " Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target "
in the following snippet, can any one tell were I am went wrong.

```
PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *vc = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:payment];
vc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your app's Apple Pay entitlement is not set up correctly.

I've noticed `canMakePayments` returns `YES` and `canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:` returns `NO` when the entitlement is not set.

(I've also noticed that they can both return `YES` when the merchant ID you set on your `PKPaymentRequest` does not match the merchant ID of your Apple Pay entitlement. In this case, your `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` will be non-nil, but presenting it logs a cryptic error in the console).

So to verify that Apple Pay is configured for your app, ensure that "Apple Pay" is "On" in the Capabilities section of your target settings, and that it has a merchant identifier (which you'll need to [set up](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios/guides/apple-pay) if you haven't already).

Then either:

- If using your direct `PassKit` integration method, ensure that you are setting `merchantIdentifier` property to the matching merchant identifier in the entitlement.

> Please check this code:

```
if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments]) {
    NSLog(@"Can Make Payments");
    PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *viewController = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
    if (!viewController) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }
    viewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Can't Make payments");
}
```

or

refer this url with sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH3-SW2

Comment: @bhardresh it working in simulator but in device it is crashing.

Comment: to which certificate i have to add the uuid

Comment: go to capabilities->Apple pay  check all contain true or red display/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123578/discussion-between-bhadresh-kathiriya-and-arun).

Answer (score 2):

Actually it will work on Simulator, but not on real device when Apple Pay **IS NOT SUPORTED** in the country the device is assigned to. Please consider this.

Answer (score 1):

// once check your controller is it initializing properly or not

```
     if (!viewController) { 
          [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
     } else {
       // handle error , may be request is not proper to initializing the    PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController
  }
```